# Tap gesture added to UIImageView not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to make `UIImageView` respond to user tap. I add image views in storyboard, and set tags to them. Then in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openCourseView:)];
[self.view viewWithTag:IMAGE_VIEW_TERM].userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.view viewWithTag:IMAGE_VIEW_1V1].userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.view viewWithTag:IMAGE_VIEW_SPECIAL].userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[[self.view viewWithTag:IMAGE_VIEW_TERM] addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[[self.view viewWithTag:IMAGE_VIEW_1V1] addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[[self.view viewWithTag:IMAGE_VIEW_SPECIAL] addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

But my response method `openCourseView:` never called. Then I tried to use `IBOutlet` to add gesture recognizer to image view, still not responding.

What's the problem?

Comment: Image views are programatically created?

Comment: No, they are added using storyboard.

Comment: Than create IBOutlets and try

Comment: Tried, but problem still exists. :-(

Comment: try with UITapGestureRecognizer

Comment: oops, good catch @LokeshChowdary !!

Comment: @LokeshChowdary Sorry to be careless, you saved my life!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake found by LokeshChowdary.

In my code, `UIGestureRecognizer` should be `UITapGestureRecognizer`.